# How to get path template in JAX-RS ContainerRequestFilter?

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy

From within a JAX-RS `ContainerRequestFilter`, I'd like to obtain the unresolved path URI of the request; i.e. something like "todos/{id}". Via `requestContext.getUriInfo().getPath()` I only get the path with parameters resolved, e.g. "todos/1". Is there any way for getting the path with parameters instead?

Answer (score 2):

You may need to just build the template. It's not that difficult. You can get access to the resource class and method (from an injected `ResourceInfo`) and just use the `UriBuilder` methods. It has `path()` methods that accept `Class` and `Method` and it will build the Uri for you based on the `@Path` annotations of those objects. Then just get the template with `UriBuilder#toTemplate()` For example

```
public class UriTestingFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context
    private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;


    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request) throws IOException {
        UriInfo uriInfo = request.getUriInfo();

        Class<?> resourceClass = resourceInfo.getResourceClass();
        Method resourceMethod = resourceInfo.getResourceMethod();

        UriBuilder partialUriBuilder = UriBuilder.fromResource(resourceClass)
                .path(resourceMethod);
        String partialUri = partialUriBuilder.toTemplate();

        URI baseUri = uriInfo.getBaseUri();
        UriBuilder fullUriBuilder = UriBuilder.fromUri(baseUri)
                .path(resourceClass)
                .path(resourceMethod);
        String fullUri = fullUriBuilder.toTemplate();
    }
}
```

Comment: One more way to obtain a `ResourceInfo` is to implement a `DynanicFeature`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ResourceInfo` doesn't really work very well with sub-resources.

It's possible to get it in Jersey from the `ContainerRequestContext` when using using this:

```
    List<UriTemplate> matchedTemplates = new ArrayList<>(ctx.getMatchedTemplates());
    Collections.reverse(matchedTemplates);
    String path = matchedTemplates.stream()
            .map(UriTemplate::getTemplate)
            .filter(s -> !s.equals("/"))
            .collect(joining());
```